# Web.Config getting authentication error

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I have the following code:
My goal is that only when the user tries to go to the **Register.aspx** page they need to be authenticated with the **Admin.aspx** page. 
I get the following message;

*It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level. This error can be caused ty a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.*

Am  I doing something wrong?

```
       <location path="Report.aspx">        
       <system.web>
         <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="Admin.aspx" >
                <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                    <user name="John" password="pass@432"/>
                </credentials>
            </forms>
         </authentication>
         <authorization>
            <deny users="*" />
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
     </location>
```

Comment: `virtual directory not being configured` do you have a Virtual Directory setup...

Comment: I do not. Why would I need a virtual directory? Why is it requesting for one?

Comment: Your current setting will deny all users from viewing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is probably sitting in a folder under your website as part of that website and not an application in its own right.

For IIS 6.1: Go into IIS, right click your applications root folder and select Convert to Application.

Give this a go and see if it helps.

If that dosn't work...

Check you are putting your authentication config in the root web.config file and not in one in a folder lower down. (for example the one sitting in the MVC views folders if using MVC).

Although not related to your problem, as someone else said you have a deny all. To deny unauthenticated users access to the page use the question mark instead of asterix.

```
 <location path="foo.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```